# plotly.express, histogram and line graph

Tags: python, pandas

I have question regarding plotly.express.
[image: picture]

I would like to have something similar like in the picture, but I would like to have histograms for categories, so for certain year there will be histogram for values on this year and the line will be representing the sum of the categories on certain date. Is it possible to make such plot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. put some code

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import numpy as np


fig = go.Figure()
fig.add_trace(go.Bar(x=[2019, 2020, 2021, 2022, 2023], y=[10, 20, 30, 40, 50], name='class1'))
fig.add_trace(go.Bar(x=[2019, 2020, 2021, 2022, 2023], y=[-30, -20, -10, -20, -10], name='class2'))
fig.add_trace(go.Line(x=[2019, 2020, 2021, 2022, 2023], y=[4, 7, 9, 0, 10], name='line'))
fig.update_layout(template='plotly_white', xaxis_title='x label', yaxis_title="y label", title="demo title")
fig.show()
fig.write_html("demo1.html")
```

2. show results:
   [image]